# When memory is filled with large variables, canvas becomes very slow

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

My idea was to save imageData to array (toDataUrl give some artifacts with canvas shadows). But then i've seen that storing it this way makes drawing really slow. Especially when use canvas filters like blur. It's obvious that they slow down drawing, but difference between having variables in memory, or not, is huge, and also bigger when I use those canvas things like blur. Also, effect when i add for example 100 steps to array doesn't seem to be much different from 2 steps

Is it because those canvas things like filters and blur require a lot of memory? My question is: How can i solve this problem the right way, so that it won't lag the canvas?

I've created demo in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-voice-v5oxhw?file=/src/index.js.

Here is also the code. When you press 'fill history' button, drawing should become very slow.

```
import "./styles.css";

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 1000;
canvas.style.width = "1000px";
canvas.style.height = "1000px";

const drawButton = document.querySelector(".draw");
const fillHistoryButton = document.querySelector(".fillHistory");

const history = [];

const draw = () => {
  ctx.filter = "blur(5px)";
  for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    console.log(i);
    ctx.arc(
      canvas.width * Math.random(),
      canvas.height * Math.random(),
      4,
      0,
      2 * Math.PI
    );
    ctx.fill();
  }
};

const fillHistory = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    console.log(i, "adding to history");
    history.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
  }
};

drawButton.addEventListener("click", draw);
fillHistoryButton.addEventListener("click", fillHistory);
```

**UPDATE**
I found the solution. It's to use offscreen canvas. The problem is that getImageData method makes canvas use CPU instead of GPU (you can't then manually set it back, it's totally up to browser). And ofc drawing with CPU is slower, but MUCH slower with effects like blur. For some reason offscreen canvas doesn't swap to gpu, so it works well. So the problem is not in big variables, and not in the slowness of getImageData method, but in fact that this method swaps canvas to use CPU

Comment: Did you just delete your original question and then basically repost it instead of editing your original question?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, i did this because they just closed it, because 'it didn't contain code in question itself', and didn't open after i edited it. I spent some time to write this, so i didn't want for it just to be closed, even if nobody would answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because the memory is filled, it's because calling `getImageData` deaccelerates your canvas: it's buffer is moved from the GPU to the CPU.
You can try to keep it always in the CPU instead, which will accelerate the call to `getImageData`, by initializing it as

```js
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
```

But your `filter` would still be slowed down a lot since it wouldn't benefit from the GPU anymore.

But anyway, to store history steps the best is to save the drawing operations, when possible, instead of storing the bitmap.
If you really need to store the bitmap, then use [`createImageBitmap(canvas)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap). This will store only the bitmap and won't require switching back to the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But somehow when `getImageData` is surely finished, for example after 30 seconds, drawing is still really slow, it's why it seemed for me that the problem is in filled memory. The problem is also that I can't save every drawing operation because number of shapes is unlimited, and user adds N number of shapes by layers. Number could be even many millions in theory.

Comment: It's expected that calling `getImageData` will slow down the canvas drawing indefinitely. It got moved to the CPU. Now you have software rendering, instead of the often faster hardware rendering (definitely faster for filters). As for storing the drawing commands, you can store a lot of commands for the same memory use than one 1000x1000px bitmap.